# Alternative to global variable

Tags: python, recursion

I got a recursive function, which reverses an integer. The reversed Integer can not start with zero, e.g.: 12340 becomes 4321.

```
res = 0
base = 1


def reverse(n):

    global res
    global base

    if n > 0:
        reverse(n // 10)
        res = res + (n % 10) * base
        base = base * 10

    return res
```

this code works, but only once and hence I want to get rid of the global variables. I thought of a helper function, inside of the `reverse(n)` function, but I could not get it to work properly. I have tried for almost an hour and would love to see the solution eventually.

Comment: A helper function would indeed be a straightforward was of solving this. What was your try and what went wrong?

Comment: I wasn't sure how to include the res and code variables in the helper function. I have tried something like `helper(n, res,base)` but it ended up in a total mess :D And if I do not include them, they do not get called , right?

Comment: As a side note: getting rid of the global variables is absolutely necessary, as the current code does **not** really work. It only works the first time you use the function. Any subsequent call would give unexpected results, as `res` and `base` wouldn't be reset between calls.

Comment: Totally, it works only once. But it worked for my very basic purpose, i.e. making a test case work

Comment: As a straightforward translation, you could create a class, Reverser, which initializes `self.res` and `self.base` to those values.  Then define `reverse` as a method of that class.

Comment: I just want to practice recursion, to be honest.

Comment: @F.V.--a simple way to remove globals would be to add a mutable argument that duplicated the value of res and base.

Comment: How do you want to handle the case where the value to reverse ends with zero?  If you call `reverse(543210)` should the result be 12345 or 012345?  If the former, is it a concern that `reverse(reverse(543210))` will not return the original input?

Comment: The reversed number should not start with 0, hence it is not a concern that reverse(reverse(543210)) does not return the original output.

Comment: @F.V. you might want to edit and add that to the question to make the requirements self-contained there.

Answer (score 7):

It's totally possible with a helper method:

```
def reverse_recursive(i: int) -> int:
    def helper(i: int, result_up_to_now: int) -> int:
        if i == 0:
            return result_up_to_now
        return helper(i // 10, result_up_to_now * 10 + (i % 10))
    return helper(i, 0)

assert reverse_recursive(123456789) == 987654321
```

And even without one:

```
def reverse_recursive_nohelper(i: int, result_up_to_now=0) -> int:
    if i == 0:
        return result_up_to_now
    return reverse_recursive_nohelper(i // 10, result_up_to_now * 10 + (i % 10))

assert reverse_recursive_nohelper(123456789) == 987654321
```

But the latter one could of course be misused/misunderstood by someone.

Just for comparison, the non-recursive version:

```
def reverse_straight(i: int) -> int:
    result = 0
    while i != 0:
        result = result*10 + i % 10
        i //= 10
    return result

assert reverse_straight(123456789) == 987654321
```

Comment: how about the variables?

Comment: @Ade_1: which variables? OP wanted to get rid of the global variables. That's what I did.

Answer (score 1):

Example of using a mutable argument to get rid of globals

```
def reverse(n, res_base = None):
    if res_base is None:
        res_base = [0, 1]    # Use two element list for res, base
                             # res_base[0] -> res
                             # res_base[1] -> base
        
    if n > 0:
        reverse(n // 10, res_base)
        # Update as in original code 
        # but replacing res & base with elements from list res_base
        res_base[0] = (res_base[0] + (n%10)*res_base[1])  # res update
        res_base[1] = res_base[1] * 10                    # base update

    return res_base[0]
```

Check that it works on multiple runs

```
print(reverse(12345)) # Output: 54321
print(reverse(6789))  # 9876
```

**Alternative Using Helper Function**

```
def reverse(n):
    def helper(n, res, base):
        if n > 0:
            res, base = helper(n // 10, res, base)
            res = res + (n % 10) * base
            base = base * 10
        return res, base
    
    res, base = helper(n, 0, 1)
    return res
        

print(reverse(12345)) # Output: 54321
print(reverse(6789))  # 9876
```

**Shows Use of Mutable Argument**

Use mutable argument removes need to pass update back to parent

```
def reverse(n):
    def helper(n, res_base):
        if n > 0:
            helper(n//10, res_base)
            res_base[0] += (n%10)*res_base[1]  # Since res_base is mutable, it's parent will see the change in value
            res_base[1] *= 10
    res_base = [0, 1]
    helper(n, res_base)
    return res_base[0]

print(reverse(12345))  # Out: 54321
```

Comment: @F.V.--updated solution with an answer to your question as an alternative.

Comment: Thank you for that! For me, it is quite confusing that the first function does not assing res_base to the function, but res and base `res, base = helper(n//10, res,base` do. In other words, why and how does res_base get updated?

Comment: @F.V.--in the conditional there are two assignments to res_base, namely:: `res_base[0] = (res_base[0] + (n%10)*res_base[1]` and `res_base[1] = res_base[1] * 10`.

Comment: yea, sorry my question was poorly worded. Why would

`helper(n // 10, res, base)`
`res = res + (n % 10) * base)`
`base = base * 10` 

not work in the second code? This seems analogous to the first code

Comment: @F.V.--seems you're wondering why I need `res, base =helper(n // 10, res, base)`, rather than just `helper(n // 10, res, base)`.  Is that right?  The issue is res & base are local variables within the helper function.  Meaning each time helper is called a new stack frame is created with it's local variables.  Thus, the parent res, base are in a different stack frame from it's children. So when the children modify res, base it does not affect the res, base in the parent.  Returning res, base to the parent allows the parent to update it's res, base.

Comment: I see, weill explained! But in the `def reverse(n, res_base = None)` function, `res_base` is called with each function aswell, but apparently there, a new frame is not created. Is that because the variable is in the parent's frame anyway?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230986/discussion-between-darrylg-and-f-v).

Answer (score 1):

global only on the agg_res variable for the result.

Anyway agg_res is reinitialized at the end of the calculation (no influence on the second re-use)

```
agg_res=0

def reverse(n, res=0, base=1):
    global agg_res
    ls = len(str(n))
    if n > 0:
        reverse(n // 10, res, base)
        res = res + (n % 10)
        base = base * (10**(ls-1))
        agg_res += res*base
    else :
        agg_res=0

# First time
reverse(5786)
print(agg_res)
# 6875

# Second time
reverse(5786)
print(agg_res)
# 6875
```